# Databinding with hierarchal data template and a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I am working on an ERP type system using Microsoft Access and WPF.  I have some questions on how to bind information to some textboxes and tree view selection.  So, before I ask the question, let me provide the background on what I have done already.

I have the following tables in my database:

```
Table: tbl_Vendors
Column: ID - Autonumber
Column: Name - string(75)

Table: tbl_Departments
Column: ID - Autonumber
Column: Name - string(100)

Table: tbl_Products
Column: ID - Autonumber
Column: Department - Number (linked to tbl_Departments.ID)
Column: Description - string(255)
Column: UPC - string(12)
Column: Price - currency

Table: tbl_Product_Vendor_Cost
Column: VendorID - number (linked to tbl_Vendors.ID)
Column: ProductID - number (linked to tbl_Products.ID)
Column: Cost - Currency
```

On my XAML window, I have a Treeview that I use a Hierarchal Data Template to work with the data, it displays the products, sorted by the department.  Here are the resources that I use:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- The data template for the products-->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="productTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- The data template for the departments-->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="treeViewTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Department2Product}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource productTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

In the window's XAML file, I have the treeview called out as such:

```
<TreeView Name="lstProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding tbl_Departments}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewTemplate}" AlternationCount="2" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
```

In the window's .cs file I have the following method defined:

```
Public void UpdateUI() {
    DataSet outResult;
    If (ProductsDatabase.TryToGetProductsDataset(out outResult)) {
        this.tvwProducts.DataContext = outResult;
    }
}
```

The UpdateUI method is called whenever a change is made to the product, or whenever the InitializeComponent method is run as well.  So, now that that is all shown, here's my actual question.  I have some textboxes on the window, when I select a product, I would like the textboxes to be filled with the data from the selected product.  I would either like to ignore any departments that are selected, or prevent the actual selection of the departments altogether, either way works.  I am going to try a couple of other things as well as I anxiously await any answers from here.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate any answers that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

So, I went a different direction with this.

The treeview gets it's own DataSet as it's data context.  I then use the same data template and hierarchal data template to display the information.  Then, in the code behind, I just made sure that, when the TreeView's SelectedValueChanged event is called, I check to see if the selected DataRowView's DataRow is from the proper table.  If it is, then I pull the product information from the database and put it into the control's data context at runtime.